# Populate and perform a Spinner in an OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, listener, spinner

I've an issue with using a spinner. For some reasons, I need to populate the spinner (`setAdapter()`) then showing it (`performClick()`) within an EditText onClickListener.

My Spinner is correctly initialized as I got no visible error. Just he won't open. The following code won't work:

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                List<String> statusStrings = new ArrayList<>();
                statusStrings.add("PROCESSING");
                statusStrings.add("LATE");
                statusStrings.add("DONE");
                statusStrings.add("REJECT");
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, statusStrings);        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                spinner.performClick();
            }
        });
```

However, the same code will work outside of the onClick event.
Furthermore, I solved my issue by placing`spinner.performClick();` in a new Thread, like this:

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    List<String> statusStrings = new ArrayList<>();
                    statusStrings.add("PROCESSING");
                    statusStrings.add("LATE");
                    statusStrings.add("DONE");
                    statusStrings.add("REJECT");
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, statusStrings);        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                    final Handler h = new Handler();
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    spinner.performClick();
                                }
                            }, 100);
                        }
                    }).start();
                }
            });
```

But this solution does not satisfy me, because I don't understand why I need to put this in a new Thread.

Any thought about this?
Thank you

Comment: **performClick** is usually used to perform an automatic click after certain amount of time ! that's why it needs to be in a separate thread. You can implement a simple OnClickListener instead , it will work on the main thread normally

Comment: Thank you but finally, I ended up using ChipView instead of ChipInput to achieve what I wanted.